# What is the purpose of using return in onsubmit parameter in Html.BeginForm?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.beginform

In an ASP.NET MVC razor view I am submitting a form on button click. If I indicate 'return' on onsubmit parameter it behaves different than If I do not indicate 'return'.

So If I parametrize BeginForm as below:

```
Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", onsubmit = "return doAction();", @class = "well" })
```

it behaves different from below one:

```
Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm", onsubmit = "doAction();", @class = "well" })
```

so What is the purpose of using return or not using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onsubmit = "doAction();"

doAction(){
   alert("Hello World!");
}
```

^ What this would do is just execute your function, and since `doAction()` isn't stopping the event from doing the default process, the form will submit.

---

```
onsubmit = "return doAction();"

doAction(){
   alert("Hello World!");
   return false; // form will not submit
   // return true; // form will submit
}
```

^ What this would do is execute your function and if your function returns a `false` boolean value, it would prevent the form from submitting.

---

To see where they exactly differ, try `onsubmit="doAction()"` and a function that returns `false`;

```
onsubmit = "doAction();"

doAction(){
   alert("Hello World!");
   return false; // the form will still submit
}
```

The form will still submit because you didn't indicate the `return` keyword despite the function returning `false`. The `return` keyword will signal the form to check the value returned by the function first.